# Problema al expandir tabla en la pagina

Tags: html

Tengo problema al expandir la tabla en mi pagina web, tengo el bootstrap y el `width=100%` pero no se logra la misión. Tengo una imagen de referencia de mi página para que puedan apreciar mi problema y me puedan ayudar de mejor manera a lo que quiero llegar.

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover" width="100%" >
                    <tr>
                        <th>Patente</th>
                        <th>Marca</th>
                        <th>Modelo</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Fecha_ingreso</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($cars as $car)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$car->patente}}</td>
                        <td>{{$car->marca}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ route('cars.edit', $car->id )}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Modificar</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="{{ route('cars.destroy', $car->id )}}" method="POST">
                                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value=Eliminar>
                            </form> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando bootstrap no necesitas ese with=100% lo que tienes que hacer es implementar correctamente el sistema de grilla. Éste sistema te permite dividir la página en filas y columnas donde luego podrás ubicar los elementos como quieras, teniendo en cuenta que cada fila tiene 12 espacios de columnas disponibles.

Primero hay que tener en cuenta que para implementar la grilla debes tener un container, ésto puede ser un div en tu página u otro elemento que sea contenedor (o sea que puedan tener elmentos hijos div, main al contrario de h1 por ejemplo que solo debe contener el texto del título). Éste container a su vez puede ser normal o fluid, el normal deja un margen a cada borde del navegador y el fluid ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla, como todo en bootstrap se realiza agregando clases, container y container-fluid respectivamente. En tu caso usaremos container-fluid:

```css
.container-fluid{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  Soy un container
</div>
```

Ahora, para crear la tabla primero debes definir dónde se ubicará en la grilla, para ello debes crear con un elmento contenedor la fila (clase row):

```css
.container-fluid{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    soy una fila
  </div>
</div>
```

Por último tenemos dos opciones, una es colocar la tabla indicando que ocupará los 12 espacios de columna de la fila y por ende todo el ancho de la pantalla:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table col-12">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
          <th>col5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>dato1</td>
          <td>dato2</td>
          <td>dato3</td>
          <td>dato4</td>
          <td>dato5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dato1</td>
          <td>dato2</td>
          <td>dato3</td>
          <td>dato4</td>
          <td>dato5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y la segunda opción es colocar un elemento contenedor, indicándole que ocupará los 12 espacios de columna, por si queremos luego agregar más cosas en éste espacio:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
            <th>col4</th>
            <th>col5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>dato1</td>
            <td>dato2</td>
            <td>dato3</td>
            <td>dato4</td>
            <td>dato5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>dato1</td>
            <td>dato2</td>
            <td>dato3</td>
            <td>dato4</td>
            <td>dato5</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <h1>Hola!</h1>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo más importante es que leas bien sobre el sistema de grilla ya que puedes tener muchas filas y muchas columnas logrando hacer cosas como:

```css
.texto{
  background-color: gray;
}

.texto2{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.texto3{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>este div ocupa los 12 espacios de columnas</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <p class="texto">este div ocupa 3 espacios de columnas</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p class="texto">este div ocupa 4 espacios de columnas</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="texto">este div ocupa el resto espacios de columnas</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p class="texto2">este div ocupa 6 espacios de columnas</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <p class="texto2">este div ocupa 6 espacios de columnas</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      <p class="texto3">este div ocupa 4 espacios de columnas y esta centrado en la fila</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```